# BasicHttpBinding, ServiceReference from WSDL - performance issues

Tags: c#, .net, performance, httpwebrequest, basichttpbinding

I am currently experiencing some difficulties diagnosing some BasicHttpBinding/ServiceReference performance issues.  In some instances, when using a `Stopwatch` to time a synchronous method call to the service, it is measured as 2.5seconds.  I have done both Wireshark (pcap) and Fiddler (INET web proxy) analysis of this same call and get back a 400ms response time which is not far from best case scenario.

So where does this 2 second discrepancy come from?

I am using the following `BasicHttpBinding`:

```
BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding
    {
        SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_settings.SendTimeout),
        ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_settings.SendTimeout),
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 100,
        Security =
        {
            Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly,
            Message = { ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName },
            Transport = { ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic }
        }
    };
```

We are using these values:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20;
ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 10000;
```

as well as compressed HttpWebRequests:

```
public class CompressibleHttpRequestCreator : IWebRequestCreate
{
    WebRequest IWebRequestCreate.Create(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HttpWebRequest),
            BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
            null,
            new object[] { uri, null },
            null) as HttpWebRequest;

        if (httpWebRequest != null)
        {
            httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip |
                                                    DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        }

        return httpWebRequest;
    }
}
```

I'm at a loss as to where this addition 2 seconds could come in - I'm am theorising when I suggest the request or response is getting queued somewhere which would delay the request but not sure where this could be?

The requests are UI/User driven and we typically only have 1-5 requests going on concurrently so `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` of 20 should be plenty.  This is occurring with and without Fiddler so I've eliminated any proxies reusing connections etc - plus it couldn't take 2 seconds to establish a new server connection, could it?

**Update:**

After some more diagnostics, I have found some interesting timings when outputting ServiceModel tracing times.

[image: ServiceModel times]

The timings, from top highlight to bottom are of these TraceIdentifiers:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/System.ServiceModel.MessageWritten.aspx (A message was written)
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageSent.aspx (Sent a message over a channel)
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseReceived.aspx (HTTP response was received)

I cannot explain why the duration between 1 and 2 could take 2+ seconds.  Any ideas?  Is it at all possible that the thread is being descheduled or something?

Comment: Have you considered that yours `MaxReceivedMessageSize = 100MB` could unneccessary cause memory allocations?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AgentFire - I have tried reducing this value but it resulted in the same issue.  Please see my new message below for further details.